# Indices out of range for MaxUnpool2d

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch, conv-neural-network, autoencoder, max-pooling

I am trying to understand unpooling in Pytorch because I want to build a convolutional auto-encoder.

I have the following code

```
from torch.autograd import Variable

data = Variable(torch.rand(1, 73, 480))
pool_t = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2, return_indices=True)
unpool_t = nn.MaxUnpool2d(2, 2)
out, indices1 = pool_t(data)
out = unpool_t(out, indices1)
```

But I am constantly getting this error on the last line (unpooling).

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Although the data is simulated in this example, the input has to be of that shape because of the preprocessing that has to be done.

I am fairly new to convolutional networks, but I have even tried using a ReLU and convolutional 2D layer before the pooling however, the indices always seem to be incorrect when unpooling for this shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is 1D and you are using 2D pooling and unpooling operations.

PyTorch interpret the first two dimensions of tensors as "batch dimension" and "channel"/"feature space" dimension. The rest of the dimensions are treated as spatial dimensions.
So, in your example, `data` is 3D tensor of size `(1, 73, 480)` and is interpret by pytorch as a single batch ("batch dimension" = 1) with 73 channels per sample and 480 samples.
For some reason `MaxPool2d` works for you and treats the channel dimension as a spatial dimension and sample this as well - I'm not sure this is a bug or a feature.

If you do want to sample along the second dimension you can add an additional dimension, making `data` a 4D tensor:

```py
out, indices1 = pool_t(data[None,...])
In [11]: out = unpool_t(out, indices1, data[None,...].size())
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense now.  I added the following to my code and it ran: ```data = Variable(torch.rand(1, 73, 480)).unsqueeze(0)```